# Loader (Gif) Not Displayed on BlackBerry Device

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry-webworks

"I have this loader gif that displayed nicely when I test it on Ripple Emulator but when being placed on the device, only the loading text is displayed but not the loader.gif

```
function getData()
{
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.somedomain.com/somedirectory/webservice​s',
  data&colon; { some data },
  beforeSend:function() 
  {
    var strLoader = "";

    strLoader += '<div id="loaderContainer">';
    strLoader += '<div id="loaderWord">Loading.....</div>';
    strLoader += '<div id="loaderImage"><img src="images/loader.gif" /></div>';
    strLoader += '</div>';//end of loaderContainer

    $('#content').html(strLoader);
  },
  success:function(data) 
  {
    //retrieve data if retrieval is successful
  }
  error:function()
  {
    //display message if there's error
  }
});
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

**edited to reflect the typos on the sample code**

Comment: There is a syntax error on `$('#content).html(strLoader);` , it's missing a `'`. Might be your problem?

Comment: First look errors : `data&colon;`, 
unnecessary `'` -> `'div id="loaderWord'>Loading.....</div>';'`

Answer (score 0):

On the line below you have used the wrong quote, ' instead of a "

```
strLoader += '<div id="loaderWord'>Loading.....</div>';
//_______________________________^ Change this to a "
```

On the line below you are missing a quote.

```
$('#content).html(strLoader);
//________^ Add a '
```

Comment: Sorry guys, those are typos in this post. But in the actual code the " and ' have been open and closed accordingly.

Comment: ah ok... just throwing ideas out there but it's not something like the blackberry can't work out the height and width of the image itself? Have you tried adding the dimensions to the image. E.g `<img src="images/loader.gif" height="100" width="100" />`

Comment: Hi vletech. Tried adding height="100" and width="100" and also have tried height="100%" and width="100%". It's still not showing.